# Prove that 2 mobile devices are close to each other

Tags: android, ios, location, google-nearby

Let's say I'm developing an app (Android, iOS or both), and 2 users (UserX & UserY) have downloaded my app with giving it all permissions needed,

If UserX opened the app telling it "hey app, I'm currently close to UserY's mobile" (like in the same room or something), where UserY's mobile could be just laying down doing nothing,

**Question is**, can the app make sure UserX's claims are valid or not? .. if yes, then is it valid for both platforms (Android & iOS)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Geofence for both user x and user y and based on the radius of geofence you can generate an alert if users cross into each others geofences.

> Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest.

You can have multiple active geofences, with a limit of 100 per app, per device user. For each geofence, you can ask Location Services to send you entrance and exit events.

Here are more info on the same - https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

Comment: Thanks, but the only problem is the accuracy, where the scenario I'm telling here needs to detect same room (like 2 or 3 meters accuracy), but as per this link https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#choose-the-optimal-radius-for-your-geofence , the accuracy can usually be 50 meters depending on available location source

Comment: How about bluetooth scanner. Not a very battery efficient solution but can work. However You would need user/system permissions to enable bluetooth of the device via your app (even if your app app is in background). here is a sample project. - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-androids-bluetooth-api--cms-24084